# Memory usage in uiwebview on iOS 7.1 versus iOS 7

Tags: ios, memory, uiwebview

Recently with the iOS 7.1 update we have noticed something odd and unexpected. Memory usage of our app (measured in Instruments and by reports from the field) has gone **down** significantly for users with iOS 7.1 compared to when they were using iOS 7.0. I can't find anything in the release notes for 7.1 or elsewhere on the web  suggesting fixes to do with optimizing memory use in webview based apps, so I can't explain it.

My question is to see if anyone else has noticed anything like this with the 7.1 update, or can you provide any answers as to why it might have occurred?

Comment: Apple made huge performance improvements (and likely fixed hundreds of bugs in the process). Very rarely does Apple note minor changes (esp. performance improvements) in their release notes. Although, it is certainly possible that they made optimizations to UIWebView. It's also possible that they haven't gotten around to updating the documentation too.

Comment: Well if that's the case it's nice to finally have some good news from an iOS update because the iOS 5.0, 6.0 and 7.0 updates were all a bit of a disaster. A win's a win I guess

Comment: Feel free to put your comment as an answer so I can accept it if you like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple made huge performance improvements (and likely fixed hundreds of bugs) in iOS 7.1. The improvements you found with `UIWebView` are likely included in those improvements. In fact I noticed `MKMapView` memory usage also improved by about 10%-15%.

Very rarely does Apple write about specific minor changes (esp. performance improvements) in their release notes:

> Performance improvements and bug fixes

Apple uses only five words to encompass hundreds of improvements and fixes.

It is also possible that Apple hasn't gotten around to fully updating the documentation.

---

See the [API diffs for iOS 7.1](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS71APIDiffs/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013973), it seems nothing was changed in UIKit (at least in the public API).

The iOS 7.1 release notes don't give away much either - just a few CFNetwork changes. There is no mention of UIWebView.